# How I can speed up row column access to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having speed issues with my code after I switched to following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=products, columns=['pk', 'product_name', 'category_name', 'brand_name'])
df.set_index(['pk'], inplace=True)
```

This is the only place I use the data frame. 'pk' is integer.

```
            category = self.product_list.iloc[int(prod)-1]['category_name']
            brand = self.product_list.iloc[int(prod)-1]['brand_name']
```

What I am doing here wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
print product_list.category_name.iat[int(prod)-1]
print product_list.brand_name.iat[int(prod)-1]
```

**Timing** (`index` - `string`):

Sample:

```
product_list = pd.DataFrame({'brand_name': {'r': 'r', 'g': 't', 'w': 'i'}, 
                             'category_name': {'r': 's', 'g': 'f', 'w': 'a'}})
print product_list
  brand_name category_name
g          t             f
r          r             s
w          i             a

In [242]: %timeit product_list.iloc[int(prod)-1]['category_name']
The slowest run took 8.27 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 82.7 µs per loop

In [243]: %timeit product_list.brand_name.iat[int(prod)-1]
The slowest run took 16.01 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.96 µs per loop
```

`index`: `int`:

```
product_list = pd.DataFrame({'brand_name': {0: 't', 1: 'r', 2: 'i'}, 
                             'category_name': {0: 'f', 1: 's', 2: 'a'}})
print product_list
  brand_name category_name
0          t             f
1          r             s
2          i             a

In [250]: %timeit product_list.iloc[int(prod)-1]['category_name']
The slowest run took 8.24 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 84.7 µs per loop

In [251]: %timeit product_list.brand_name.iat[int(prod)-1]
The slowest run took 24.17 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.86 µs per loop
```

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!